# Security Questions on jQuery Ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security

### **Question in Short:**

Is there a way to hide the submission page of jQuery ajax method?

### Problem Description:

I have a webpage where I will post some data to another php for processing and then send all the data back to the page using AJAX methods.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post( 'process.php',
           {data1:12345, data2: 23456},
           function(html){
             $('#content').append(html);
           };
  });
});
```

And obviously the codes above exposed the page in which I process the data. And the process.php goes likes this:

```
<?php 

require("db.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$d1 = $_POST['data1'];
$d2 = $_POST['data2'];
$jsondata = array();

while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $row['d3'] = calculateA($d1,$d2,$row['A'],$row['B']);
  $jsondata = $row;
}

echo json_encode($jsondata);

?>
```

Now hackers or intruders can easily link a page and using AJAX method to call on my page, then the hacker will easily have my `$jsondata` in their hands. I have studied some of the websites, I am not able to find their "submission page" link. Therefore, I am wondering how they do it.

Comment: If the JSON data you're returning is so sensitive that it endangers the security of your application, you should not return that data.

Comment: It seems you need some kind of authorization mechanism that only authorized requests are allowed. So who would be allowed to do a request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disguise requests made from the browser - as the browser (and by extension the user) is initiating them.

You can obfuscate the source, but the request will still show up in some where: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), http://www.wireshark.org/ (protocol analyser),  on a firewall, ISP logs etc.

If you want to see the requests made by other sites, install one of the above tools.

Comment: Does that mean everyone will be able to see my process.php and manipulate on it? How do I prevent people from doing so?

Comment: As long as your server is configured correctly (read: PHP runs) people cannot see the `process.php` code, only its output.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to hide the submission page of jQuery ajax method?

No.

> the hacker will easily have my $jsondata in their hands.

Just like they have HTML source of your pages as well. That's how the web works.

> I am not able to find their "submission page" link.

Study them better.

Comment: Does that mean everyone will be able to see my process.php and manipulate on it? How do I prevent people from doing so for security purpose?

Comment: what do you mean with "see"? See it's code? no. What do you mean with "manipulate"? Sending requests to it? yes. every script on the every site can be "manipulated" this way. What certain security problem you see here?